# Can the field of Laurent series be made into an Archimedean ordered field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, laurent-series, formal-power-series, ordered-fields

In today's analysis class, my professor introduced the field of formal Laurent series $\Bbb R((x))$. He also talked about the dictionary order on $\Bbb R((x))$ and why it is not an Archimedean ordered field. One natural question arises:

> Can $\Bbb R((x))$ be made into an Archimedean ordered field?

My professor answered that there are uncountably orders on $\Bbb R((x))$, but none that he knows of make it an Archimedean field. Since we know that [every Archimedean field can be embedded into the real number](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1473770/does-there-exist-a-maximal-archimedean-ordered-field) and conversely, every subfield of $\Bbb R$ is Archimedean, the question transforms into:

> Can $\Bbb R((x))$ (as a field) be embedded into $\Bbb R$?

The new formulation doesn't seem easier, but it makes the problem a purely algebraic one.

---

Thanks for nombre's answer, $\Bbb R((x))$ cannot be embedded into $\Bbb R$ for the simple reason that it contains a copy of $\Bbb R$. Now I wonder if $\Bbb Q((x))$ embeds into $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 4):

In general no proper extension of $\mathbb{R}$ can be embedded into $\mathbb{R}$, otherwise their would be two distinct embeddings of $\mathbb{R}$ into itself. (see any Archimedean ordered field embeds *uniquely* into $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wonder then if $\Bbb Q[[x]]$ embeds into $\Bbb R$.

Answer (score 3):

There is no embedding
$f:\Bbb{Q}[[x]]\to \Bbb{R}$ neither: take $n\in \Bbb{Z}$ such that $f(1+nx)=1+nf(x)< 0$ then $f((1+nx)^{1/2})$ is purely imaginary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you talking about the puiseux series? The field of laurent series doesn't allow fractional exponents.

Comment: @metaverse $(1+nx)^{1/2}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {1/2\choose k} n^k x^k$ is in $\Bbb{Q}[[x]]$

Comment: Oh, this is Newton's generalized binomial theorem, many thanks!